# How do you include a port number when using Embarcadero C++ TRESTRequest

Tags: rest, c++builder

Here's the compulsory code snippet:

```
UnicodeString SeizonshaRest::doStuff(UnicodeString strEmail, UnicodeString strPassword)
{
    restclient->BaseURL = "http://localhost";
    restrequest->Resource = ":60800/home/login";
    restrequest->Params->AddItem("email", strEmail);
    restrequest->Params->AddItem("password", strPassword);
    UnicodeString strId;
    restrequest->Execute();
    strId = respMain->Content;
    return strId;
}
```

I know this is the wrong way to do it.
What's the correct way to add a port number please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port number is attached to the server hostname that the client connects to, not to the resource that the client requests once connected.

Try this:

```
restclient->BaseURL = "http://localhost:60800";
restrequest->Resource = "home/login";
```

If you read the documentation, it says:

[TCustomRESTClient.BaseURL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTClient.BaseURL)

> Specifies the base URL for all API calls.
>
> All resources and parameters of your requests will be appended to this URL. **Please, be aware that a trailing forward slash ("/") is added to the value of the BaseURL property.**

[TCustomRESTRequest.Resource](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.Resource)

> **This property is added to the base URL to establish a complete URL for the HTTP request.**
>
> **Important**: The Resource value should meet the following limitations:
>
> - Does not include the scheme or domain mame.
> - Does not include the leading slash.

So, your original code would have produced the request URL as `http://localhost/:60800/home/login`, but the correct URL is `http://localhost:60800/home/login` instead.

Comment: Thank you Mr Lebeau for your fast answer.
I have amended my function to the following:

    UnicodeString SeizonshaRest::doStuff()
    {
     //clientMain->BaseURL = "http://localhost:60800";
     //reqMain->Resource = "/login";
     //UnicodeString strReply;
     //reqMain->Execute();
     //strReply = respMain->Content;
     //return strReply;
     return "xxx";
    }

It performs as expected and returns "xxx" but if I uncomment the line

    clientMain->BaseURL = "http://localhost:60800";

the function throws an 'Access violation' 'RESTComponents220.bpl' error.

Comment: Why are you omitting the `http://` scheme from the `BaseURL`?  Don't do that. Use what I showed you. Also, did you verify that `clientMain` is even a valid object when `doStuff()` is called?  Where is `clientMain` being created?

Comment: Thanks again for our speedy reply and patience.
I added a new unit as detailed here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/22694
I then added the following extra properties to the header file:

  TRESTClient *clientMain;
  TRESTRequest *reqMain;
  TRESTResponse *respMain;
  UnicodeString doStuff(UnicodeString strEmail, UnicodeString strPassword);

Along with the following include directives:

#include <Data.Bind.Components.hpp>
#include <Data.Bind.ObjectScope.hpp>
#include <IPPeerClient.hpp>
#include <REST.Client.hpp>

Comment: I'm calling the function from a click method on a form and without all the rest stuff, it happily returns the string "xxx".
The missing 'http://' was a typo on my part.

Comment: "I then added the following extra properties to the header file" - it sounds like you simply added the REST object pointers to your class but did not actually instantiate the REST objects themselves at runtime before the class tried to use them. Is that actually the case? That would certainly account for an AV. If you have not already done so, add a constructor and destructor to your class to create/destroy the REST objects, eg:  `clientMain = new TRESTClient(NULL); reqMain = new TRESTRequest(NULL); respMain = new TRESTResponse(NULL);` ... `delete clientMain; delete reqMain; delete respMain;`

Comment: It's been a while and I've finally returned to my project and got something working.
Thanks for being so cool.

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to post my code as I can find NO examples of this ANYWHERE

contact.h:

```
#ifndef contactH
#define contactH
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <IPPeerClient.hpp> 
#include <REST.Client.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class contact;

class contact
{
   public:
      contact();
      ~contact() {};
      String connect(String query);
      TRESTClient *clientContact;
      TRESTRequest *reqContact;
      TRESTResponse *respContact;
   private:
};
```

contact.cpp:

```
String contact::connect(String query)
{
    clientContact = new TRESTClient(NULL);
    reqContact = new TRESTRequest(NULL);
    respContact = new TRESTResponse(NULL);
    reqContact->Client = clientContact;
    reqContact->Response = respContact;
    UnicodeString strUrl = "http://myawesomeurl:5150";
    reqContact.Resource = query;
    clientContact->BaseURL = strUrl;
    UnicodeString strInspect;
    reqContact->Execute();
    strInspect = respContact->Content;
    return strInspect;
}
```

I hope this helps someone as stuck for examples as I was.